# how to use Like any, like all in spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, dremio

I was trying to use like any and like all in this query in Spark/ Dremio SQL

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where col_name LIKE ANY (CONCAT('%', 10, '%'), CONCAT('%', 20, '%'), CONCAT('%', 12, '%'))
SELECT * FROM table_name where col_name LIKE ALL (CONCAT('%', 10, '%'), CONCAT('%', 20, '%'), CONCAT('%', 12, '%'))
```

it is. showing error :

> Failure parsing the query.

BY USING any I want to select all the rows with either 10, 20 or 12values and by using all I was trying to get a value which has all 3 values in it.
kindly help in resolving the query

Comment: SELECT * FROM table_name where col_name LIKE '%10%' AND col_name LIKE '%20%' AND col_name LIKE '%12%'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM table_name where col_name LIKE '%10%' AND col_name LIKE '%20%' AND col_name LIKE '%12%'

SELECT * FROM table_name where col_name LIKE '%10%' OR col_name LIKE '%20%' OR col_name LIKE '%12%'
```